# How to make Perl 6 grammar produce more than one match (like :ex and :ov)?

Tags: raku

I want `grammar` to do something like this:

```perl6
> "abc" ~~ m:ex/^ (\w ** 1..2) (\w ** 1..2) $ {say $0, $1}/
｢ab｣｢c｣
｢a｣｢bc｣
```

Or like this:

```perl6
> my regex left { \S ** 1..2  }
> my regex right { \S ** 1..2  }
> "abc" ~~ m:ex/^ <left><right> $ {say $<left>, $<right>}/
｢ab｣｢c｣
｢a｣｢bc｣
```

Here is my `grammar`:

```perl6
grammar LR {
  regex TOP {
    <left> 
    <right>
  }
  regex left {
    \w ** 1..2 
  }
  regex right {
    \w ** 1..2 
  }
}

my $string = "abc";
my $match = LR.parse($string);
say "input: $string";
printf "split: %s|%s\n", ~$match<left>, ~$match<right>;
```

Its output is:

```bash
$ input: abc
$ split: ab|c
```

So, `<left>` can be only greedy leaving nothing to `<right>`. How should I modify the code to match both possible variants?

```bash
$ input: abc
$ split: a|bc, ab|c
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Grammars are designed](https://docs.raku.org/language/grammar_tutorial) to give zero or one answers, not more than that, so you have to use some tricks to make them do what you want.

Since [`Grammar.parse`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/parse) returns just one `Match` object, you have to use a different approach to get all matches:

```
sub callback($match) {
    say $match;
}
grammar LR {
    regex TOP {
        <left> 
        <right>
        $
        { callback($/) }
        # make the match fail, thus forcing backtracking:
        <!>
    }
    regex left {
        \w ** 1..2 
    }
    regex right {
        \w ** 1..2 
    }
}

LR.parse('abc');
```

Making the match fail by calling the `<!>` assertion (which always fails) forces the previous atoms to backtrack, and thus finding different solutions. Of course this makes the grammar less reusable, because it works outside the regular calling conventions for grammars.

Note that, for the caller, the `LR.parse` seems to always fail; you get all the matches as calls to the callback function.

A slightly nicer API (but the same approach underneath) is to use `gather`/`take` to get a sequence of all matches:

```
grammar LR {
    regex TOP {
        <left> 
        <right>
        $
        { take $/ }
        # make the match fail, thus forcing backtracking:
        <!>
    }
    regex left {
        \w ** 1..2 
    }
    regex right {
        \w ** 1..2 
    }
}

.say for gather LR.parse('abc');
```

Comment: I never thought about using `gather` and `take` with code inside `regexes`, what a wonderful method! And thanks for the whole answer, it's very useful for me in many ways!

Answer (score 4):

I think Moritz Lenz, nickname moritz, author of the upcoming book ["Parsing with Perl 6 Regexes and Grammars"](https://leanpub.com/perl6regex), is the person to ask about this. I probably should have just asked him to answer this SO...

## Notes

In case anyone considers attempting to modify `grammar.parse` so that it supports `:exhaustive`, or otherwise hacking things to do what @evb wants, the following documents potentially useful inspiration/guidance that I gleaned from spelunking the relevant speculations document ([S05](https://github.com/perl6/specs/blob/master/S05-regex.pod)) and searching the #perl6 and #perl6-dev irc logs.

**7 years ago** Moritz added [an edit of S05](https://github.com/perl6/specs/commit/c482819d8c768b9ae76968739fade6525750aa36):

> A [regex] modifier that affects only the calling behaviour, and not the regex itself [eg `:exhaustive`] may only appear on constructs that involve a call (like `m//` [or `grammar.parse`]), and not on `rx//` [or `regex { ... }`].

(The [eg `:exhaustive`], [or `grammar.parse`], and [or `regex { ... }`] bits are extrapolations/interpretations/speculations I've added in this SO answer. They're not in the linked source.)

**5 years ago** Moritz [expressed interest in implementing `:exhaustive`](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2012-02-20#i_5179576) for matching (not parsing) features. Less than 2 minutes later jnthn showed a one liner that demo'd how he guessed he'd approach it. Less than 30 minutes later Moritz posted [a working prototype](https://gist.github.com/moritz/1869161). The [final version landed 7 days later](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/e46bfea35d).

**1 year ago** Moritz said on #perl6 (**emphasis** added by me): ["regexes and grammars **aren't** a good tool to find all possible ways to parse a string"](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2016-08-30#i_13117661).

Hth.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it's `:ex`! I wonder, if `regexes` and `grammars` aren't a good tool... to parse, then what is?

Comment: And do you know, is it possible to get access / buy the part of Moritz's book, which has already been completed?

Comment: @EugeneBarsky "then what is?" -- right?!? I'll let Moritz explain what he meant. First, the quote now links back to the source of the quote to make it one click to read it in its original context. Maybe that'll help. Second, I'm going to go ask Moritz to drop in here. Hth.

Comment: You have to read my quote in context; somebody asked about input that leads to ambiguous parse trees; something that is common in natural language processing, for example. In this case, trying to use regexes/grammars to get all combinations leads to an exponential explosion of parse trees, so the whole approach is flawed. Use regexes/grammars for tokenization in this case, and build some kind of statistical model or so on top. Don't expect regexes to be magic :-)

Comment: Re my book, a preview isn't available, but it's scheduled to be published in November or December 2017, so you don't have to wait terribly long. It's available for preorder: http://amzn.to/2y4EQWG and if you want to be notified when it's published, sign up for the mailing list at https://perl6book.com or follow `@perl6org` on twitter.